# Can I get the "Image Size", etc. from a NetEncoder in an existing net from the Repository?

Tags: neural-networks

I want to get the details about the input used to train a net in the Net Repository, in my case "LeNet Trained on MNIST Data". I can get its decoder by:

```
NetExtract[ NetModel["LeNet Trained on MNIST Data"] , "Input" ]
```

but I cannot figure out how to get properties like Type and ImageSize from inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sol = NetExtract[NetModel["LeNet Trained on MNIST Data"], "Input"]
FullForm[sol]
```

or look at all the elements:

```
sol[[All]]

<|"ImageSize" -> {28, 28}, "ColorSpace" -> "Grayscale", 
  "ColorChannels" -> 1, "MeanImage" -> None, "VarianceImage" -> None|>
```

This is in the form of an Association. You can extract the keys or the values directly:

```
Keys[sol[[All]]]
{"ImageSize", "ColorSpace", "ColorChannels", "MeanImage", "VarianceImage"}

Values[sol[[All]]]
{{28, 28}, "Grayscale", 1, None, None}
```

or directly grab the items of interest:

```
sol[[All]]["ImageSize"]
{28, 28}

sol[[All]]["ColorSpace"]
Grayscale
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I do not necessarily need it, but the input Type (in this case "Image") lives outside the association. Is there a way to get it?